# how to swap numbers in kotlin using function?

Tags: android, kotlin

Could someone tell me what is wrong in my code? I have been trying to do this using functions only.

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    var a = 10;
    var b = 15;
    
    println("Before swapping $a $b")
    swap(a,b)
    println("After swapping $a $b")
}
fun swap(a: Int,b:Int) : Unit{
   var a=a
    var b=b
    val temp = a
    a= b
    b=temp
}
```

Comment: You are making new a, b variables and setting the values of those - so the original variables are untouched

Comment: The parameters in the function are of type val by default. Is there any way that they can be var?

Comment: @ShahrukhAnsari: No, there is no way.  See [Parameters are Immutable](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  What you're trying to do is outright impossible with `Int`s.  You straight-up can't do that in Kotlin, because `Int`s are passed by value, not reference.

(And Kotlin told you you can't, by making it impossible to modify your original `a` and `b`.  Making new variables named the same doesn't help.)

Answer (score -2):

**Kotlin** has its own built-in "swap" function called `also{}`, which is one of the 5 **scope functions**.

> Function **also{}** takes the calling object as a parameter and returns itself, more precisely, returns its value at the time it was called. And inside the function body, you can do whatever you want.

Following is an example:

[image]

Comment: please include code as text rather than image

Comment: @Shahrukh Ansari Does my answer help?

Comment: @SamChen Yes, there are a number of ways we could swap and this is one of them